# stopped-calculation error when add alert with strategy on tradingview using pine script V5

Tags: pine-script

[image]

my strategy works well locally on Tradingview.
However,alert added to it reports error shown in the above image.

```
numberOfUptrendBar_Cycle()=>
    offset=0
    UptrendBarCounts=0

    while close[offset]>=MA[offset]
        if close[offset]>close[offset+1]
            UptrendBarCounts := UptrendBarCounts+1  
        offset := offset+1

    UptrendBarCounts//return value of this function
MA = sma(close,20)
```

I delete

```
UptrendBarCounts := UptrendBarCounts+1
```

change it to something irrelevant like

```
offset := 1
```

the error on alert disappears.

Why this happens?

Whole code shown as below:

```
//@version=5
strategy('YTStrategy', overlay=true, margin_long=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=2*100, currency=currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=true)


MASource = close
  

MA=ta.sma(close, 30)   
plot(MA, 'MA', color=color.new(#FF6D00, 0))  

numberOfUptrendBar_Cycle()=>
    offset=0
    UptrendBarCounts=0

    while MASource[offset]>MA[offset]
        if MASource[offset]>MASource[offset+1]
            UptrendBarCounts := UptrendBarCounts+1  
        offset := offset+1

    UptrendBarCounts//return value of this function
    

ofutb = numberOfUptrendBar_Cycle()

                
isNoneActiveTrade = strategy.position_size==0
isBuyTime() =>
    if isNoneActiveTrade and ofutb<=4
        MASource[1] > MA[1]   
    else
        0


isExitTime = MASource < MA and strategy.position_size != 0 



strategy.entry('LFG', strategy.long, when=isBuyTime())
strategy.close('LFG', when=isExitTime)
```

Comment: Can you add your whole code?

Comment: code added~~Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add terms for runtime on alert. Add a `if statement` to specify the lastbar alone have the right to use the while loop,which reduces tons of calculation work during alert runtime on tradingview server.
When `ThreeCommasBotMode` is set to false,that's the time when I got strategy backtesting locally,I have my full swing to while loop every bar on history.

```
numberOfUptrendBar_Cycle()=>
    offset=0
    UptrendBarCounts=0
    if ThreeCommasBotMode == true 
        if barstate.islast 
            while MASource[offset]>=MA[offset]
                if MASource[offset]>MASource[offset+1]
                    UptrendBarCounts := UptrendBarCounts+1  
                offset := offset+1
    else
        while MASource[offset]>=MA[offset]
            if MASource[offset]>MASource[offset+1]
                UptrendBarCounts := UptrendBarCounts+1  
            offset := offset+1
            
    UptrendBarCounts//return value of this function
```